# Set textbox to readonly and background color to grey in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, background-color

Good day,

I would like to make a text box in my `jsp` to become `readonly` and its background color to grey like `disable` in Jquery. The following is my code :

```
if(a)
  $('#billAccountNumber').attr('readonly', 'true');
```

I not prefer using `attr('disable', 'true');`, because the value will become null when I submit form. Any ideas instead of write second line of code to change the style?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a variable for the disabled field and once you submit you can use that variable instead of pulling it out. this way you should not get a NULL value.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I need to changed a lot in my backend code, thus, I would prefer use back the same variable.

Comment: Perhaps `disabled = true`?

Comment: `disabled = true` will make the value to null when I submit form.

Comment: Can you check this http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/67ggg/ if this is what you need

Answer (score 52, accepted):

there are 2 solutions:

visit this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvvcd/)

```
in your css you can add this:
     .input-disabled{background-color:#EBEBE4;border:1px solid #ABADB3;padding:2px 1px;}

in your js do something like this:
     $('#test').attr('readonly', true);
     $('#test').addClass('input-disabled');
```

Hope this help.

Another way is using hidden input field as mentioned by some of the comments. However bear in mind that, in the backend code, you need to make sure you validate this newly hidden input at correct scenario. Hence I'm not recommend this way as it will create more bugs if its not handle properly.

Comment: Add color inside, `.input-disabled{background-color:#EBEBE4;border:1px solid #ABADB3;padding:2px 1px;color:rgb(84, 84, 84);}` , perfect.

Answer (score 10):

As per you question this is what you can do

**HTML**

```
<textarea id='sample'>Area adskds;das;dsald da'adslda'daladhkdslasdljads</textarea>
```

**JS/Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $('#sample').attr('readonly', 'true'); // mark it as read only
    $('#sample').css('background-color' , '#DEDEDE'); // change the background color
});
```

or add a class in you css with the required styling

```
$('#sample').addClass('yourclass');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/67ggg/)**

Let me know if the requirement was different

Comment: In case anyone is considering the second option: I was able to add a class to change the background color but the events related to that class do not fire for the object that has the new class.

Answer (score 3):

If supported by your browser, you may use [CSS3 `:read-only` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_read-only.asp):

```
input[type="text"]:read-only {
    cursor: normal;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you place the account number in a div. Style it as you please and then have a hidden input in the form that also contains the account number. Then when the form gets submitted, the value should come through and not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Can add disable like below and can get data on submit. something like this ..
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbe65/7/)

Html

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="email" />
<input type="text" id="dis" class="disable" value="email"   name="email" >
```

JS

```
 $("#dis").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

CSS

```
    .disable { opacity : .35; background-color:lightgray; border:1px solid gray;}
```