# Javascript strip after X characters prior to form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE** Using the solutions provided below I added this with no luck?

```
<script>
$('.LogIn_submit').on('click',function(){
    var value=$('#Log_In_group_2_FieldB').val();
    value=value.replace(/^\s\d{6}(?=\-)&/, '')
    alert(value);
});
</script>
```

Here are the form elements if, hoping it's a simple fix:

```
<input id="Log_In_group_2_FieldB" name="Log_In_group_2_FieldB" type="password" value="<?php echo((isset($_GET["invalid"])?ValidatedField("login","Log_In_group_2_FieldB"):"".((isset($_GET["failedLogin"]) || isset($_GET["invalid"]))?"":((isset($_COOKIE["RememberMePWD"]))?$_COOKIE["RememberMePWD"]:""))  ."")); ?>" class="formTextfield_Medium" tabindex="2" title="Please enter a value.">

<input class="formButton" name="LogIn_submit" type="submit" id="LogIn_submit" value="Log In"   tabindex="5">
```

/***** Beginning Question ******/

Using [this question/answers's fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034939/set-textbox-to-readonly-and-background-color-to-grey-in-jquery) I can see how they used javascript like this:

```
$('.btnfetchcont').on('click',function(){
    var value=$('#txtCont').val();
    value=value.replace(/^(0|\+\d\d) */, '')
    alert(value);
});
```

I currently have a value that starts with 6 characters, ends in a dash and the up to 3 digits can follow the dash.

Exmaple 1: 123456-01

Example 2: 123456-9

Example 3: 123456-999

I've tried to insert a - in the value.replace cod with no luck.  How do I remove the - and any values after this on submit so that I'm only submitting the first 6 digits?

Comment: `/^\d{6}(?=\-)$/` here is regexp that you can use for that.

Comment: If you just want the first X amount of characters, regex shouldn't be necessary at all. See the answer by @Loading..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you want to have only first 6 characters from the string.

Use `.split()` or `substring(start, end)` to get the parts of string.

```js
var string = "123456-01";
console.log(string.split('-')[0]);
console.log(string.substring(0,6));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco If your requirement is always going to be 6 characters no matter what, use `.substring(0,6)`, if your requirement is always going to be "before a hyphen", use `.split('-')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use split instead of regex

```
 value=value.split("-")[0];
```

fix for your regex

```
/(-[0|\+\d\d]*)/g
```

```js
function extractNumber(value){
  return value.replace(/(-[0|\+\d\d]*)/g, '');
}
console.log(extractNumber("123456-01"));
console.log(extractNumber("123456-9"));
console.log(extractNumber("123456-999"));
```

Comment: Updated the question, doesn't seem to work in my actual sample, see above please

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** the `.split('-')` answer is better than the following, imo.

Assuming you always want just the first 6 characters, something like this should do what you want:

```
$('.btnfetchcont').on('click',function(){
    var value = $('#txtCont').val();
    value = value.substr(0, 6);
    alert(value);
});
```

or combine the two lines:

```
var value = $('#txtCont').val().substr(0, 6);
```

Read about `.substr()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

If you want to get everything before the dash, do something like this:

```
var value = $('#txtCont').val().match(/(\d*)-(\d*)/);
```

`value` is now an array where `value[0]` is the original string, `value[1]` is every digit before the dash, and `value[2]` is every digit after the dash.

This works for digits only. If you want any character instead of just digits, replace `\d` with `.`. i.e: `.match(/(.*)-(.*)/)`.

Comment: Tried it, updated question so you can see, maybe it's a typo on my part?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco The regex you've just put in the update is not right at all - what is it exactly you're trying to do? Get the first 6 characters as `value` or remove the first six characters from `value`?

Comment: Yes, I want to strip out everything but the first 6 characters prior to form submission on the password field.  input id="Log_In_group_2_FieldB"

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco then use `value = value.substr(0, 6)` - no regex necessary.

Comment: It just doesn't seem to work.  Can you update your answer with the values I provided in the updated question or do a Fiddle please?